# Evaluating definite integral of absolute value cosx using sums

Tags: definite-integrals, absolute-value

I have been working on this question for a while and my answer is not correct. The question is to evaluate this integral in terms of sums without absolute values. Here's what I have, but the answer is not correct and I can't seem to catch why:

$\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} \vert \cos x \vert dx$
$ = \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \cos x + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} -\cos x$
$ = [\cos(\pi/2) - \cos(\pi/3)] + [-\cos(\pi) - (-\cos(\pi/2))]$
$ = -\cos(\pi/3) + 1$
$ = 0.5$

**Sorry for the formatting but when I type 'pi' it doesn't change to the symbol

Comment: Write \pi instead pi.

Comment: @Aqua thank you so much :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primitive of $\cos$ is $\sin,$ not $\cos$ again.

That is, you should have $$\int{ \cos x \mathrm d x}=\sin x + c.$$

Comment: I knew it was something simple, thanks so much.

Comment: Such absurd slips happen to me too sometimes. :)

Comment: now after doing it with the correct primitive i'm getting -sin(pi/3) which also isnt correct?

Comment: @EmmaPascoe You should have $$(\sin(\frac π2)-\sin(\frac π3))-(\sin π-\sin(\frac π2))=2\sin(\frac π2)-\sin(\frac π3)-\sin π=2(1)-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}-0.$$

Comment: seems to just be one of those days... thanks though :))